# request.query does not print the query in Fastify (querystring)

Tags: javascript, node.js, schema, fastify, request.querystring

I searched for ages, but it just wouldn't print the query, I've no idea what I should do. I'm also kind of new to Fastify. Also I'm sending the request to `127.0.0.1/?greeting=something`.

```js
const opts = {
  schema: {
    querystring: {
      type: 'object',
      required: ['greeting'],
      properties: {
        greeting: {type: 'string'},
      },
    },

    response: {
      200: {
        type: 'object',
        properties: {
          status: {type: 'object'}, // i've abosulutely no idea what the type should be
        },
      },
    },
  },

  handler: async (request, reply) => {
    reply.send({
      status: request.query,
    })
  }
}
```

Can someone please help me in resolving this ?

Comment: im really sorry i just realised i can do request.query.greeting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't see the `request.query` output because of the response's schema.

The response schema filters out all the fields that are not defined, so the `properties` field lists the `status` key as object without any properties.

You should change it to:

```
status: { type: 'object', additionalProperties: true }
```

or adding the `greetings` property.

You can read about it here: https://github.com/fastify/fast-json-stringify#additionalProperties

Comment: Thanks! That's new to me. By the way, `request.query.greeting` works.